# How to Add Rows to WPF dataGrid when "Add" button click?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid, datarow

Here am using the below code for adding rows to wpf datagrid,but if am again click to add means the row cannot be added and previous row replaced by new added details....So how to make possible to add new more rows based on add button click externally.
Here the code a using ,its working for one row only added in datagrid,So how to make more new adding rows with externally button click.

```
    private void AddButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        if (!dt.Columns.Contains("Department"))
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("Department");
        }
        if (!dt.Columns.Contains("ScanTest"))
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("ScanTest");
        }
        if (!dt.Columns.Contains("Doctor"))
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("Doctor");
        }
        if (!dt.Columns.Contains("Date"))
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("Date");
        }
        if (!dt.Columns.Contains("Rate"))
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("Rate");
        }
        dr["Department"] = comboBox4.Text.ToString();
        dr["ScanTest"] = comboBox5.Text.ToString();
        dr["Doctor"] = comboBox6.Text.ToString();
        dr["Date"] = datePicker1.SelectedDate.Value;
        dr.ItemArray[0] = comboBox4.Text.ToString();
        dr.ItemArray[1] = comboBox5.Text.ToString();
        dr.ItemArray[2] = comboBox6.Text.ToString();

        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

Comment: @bilal: how to calculate the two rows "rate"?

Comment: I couldn't understand what do you want?

Comment: @bilal i need to code dr["Scantest"] + dr["Scantest"] value to another textbox ,if we add new row(calculate dr["Scantest"] + dr["Scantest"] )

Comment: You want to sum up the column dr["Scantest"] ? For example if the column have values 1,2,3 when button clicks the new row column dr["Scantest"] have value 4 then the rate will be 10?

Comment: @bilal:yes absolutely right

Comment: Simple, Initialize a variable outside the button click scope for example
int sum=0;// initialize outside the button click scope
add this line in button click scope.
sum=sum+ Convert.ToInt32(comboBox5.text);
dr["ScanTest"]=sum.tostring();

Comment: @bilal: WORKING PERFECTLY BILAL,AM STUCK HERE TWO DAYS,NOW PERFECTECTLY FINE FROM UR CODE

Comment: @bilal: Again one doubt,How to remove the selected dataGridItem with delete button externally? am coded like this:                                            var currentRowIndex = dataGrid1.Items.IndexOf(dataGrid1.CurrentItem);
dataGrid1.Items.RemoveAt(currentRowIndex);//But shows error as itemsource present,

Comment: Always show your efforts in terms of code, when you have a question.

Comment: @bilal:want to post another as a question?

Comment: @bilal:  How to check duplicate values in dataGrid,when add button is clicked???with the same above questioon

Comment: please show your efforts i think you are doing assignment, giving code for assignment is bad.

Comment: @bilal : am tried these all two days before,so that am asked,soo please help

Comment: How to check duplicate values in grid?
when add button clicked
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows) // Loop over the rows.
 {
                row["ColumnNam].tostring().equals(textbox.text) && keep checking if the condition return true than duplicate else insert 
        }

Comment: @bilal :This is the same am also used,it always shows message as "Already present"(if it we add first time also)

Comment: Paste your code here.

Comment: @bilal:working fine with ur code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time when you click the button a new `Data Table` is created and each time you add new single row in to it. Initialize the `Data Table` outside this function

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); //remove this line from button click
```

Comment: Here how to calculate two rate if new row added?

Comment: ask a new question Ramji